# How to repeat previous row values until another field changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to repeat a value from one row if there is no change between a column value in the row before.  Thanks in advance!

```
create table #results (
    [Floor] varchar(20)
    ,Room varchar(20)
    ,CheckInTime datetime

)

INSERT INTO #results
  
VALUES
  ('Floor1','Room1','2020-01-01 12:00:00'),
  ('Floor1','Room2','2020-01-05 19:00:00'),
  ('Floor1','Room3','2020-01-20 08:02:00'),
  ('Floor2','Room1','2020-01-23 19:32:00'),
  ('Floor1','Room1','2020-02-01 20:00:00')
```

And the expected result I am looking for is

[image: here]

in the "WantedValue" column.  So if Floor is the same as the row before it, use the CheckInTime value from the row before. But this needs to carry down through multiple rows potentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as you want the minimum date/time every time the floor changes.

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups.  Then use a window function to "spread" the minimum value:

```
select r.*,
       min(checkintime) over (partition by grp order by checkintime) as wantedvalue
from (select r.*,
              sum(case when prev_floor = floor then 0 else 1 end) over (order by checkintime) as grp
      from (select r.*,
                   lag(floor) over (order by checkintime) as prev_floor
            from results r
           ) r
     ) r
order by checkintime;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec0ef3b50fca52922662443aa1220e81) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This should wok

```
create table #results (
    [Floor] varchar(20)
    ,Room varchar(20)
    ,CheckInTime datetime

)

INSERT INTO #results
  
VALUES
  ('Floor1','Room1','2020-01-01 12:00:00'),
  ('Floor1','Room2','2020-01-05 19:00:00'),
  ('Floor1','Room3','2020-01-20 08:02:00'),
  ('Floor2','Room1','2020-01-23 19:32:00'),
  ('Floor1','Room1','2020-02-01 20:00:00')
  select
  a.Floor,
  a.Room,
  a.CheckInTime,
  b.CheckInTime
  from #results a
  left Join
  (
  select [Floor],MIN(CheckInTime) AS CheckInTime
  from #results group by [Floor]
  ) b
  ON a.[Floor]=b.[Floor]

  drop table #results
```

Output

```
Floor   Room    CheckInTime              CheckInTime
Floor1  Room1   2020-01-01 12:00:00.000 2020-01-01 12:00:00.000
Floor1  Room2   2020-01-05 19:00:00.000 2020-01-01 12:00:00.000
Floor1  Room3   2020-01-20 08:02:00.000 2020-01-01 12:00:00.000
Floor2  Room1   2020-01-23 19:32:00.000 2020-01-23 19:32:00.000
Floor1  Room1   2020-02-01 20:00:00.000 2020-01-01 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: The last Floor1 should have a date of 2020-02-01 20:00:00 as something happened in between.